# Swift: Searching the object from the memory address

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am typecasting the tableview cells to a custom cell

```
let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("theCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BooksTableViewCell
```

and the custom cell is created as below

```
class BooksTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var subTitleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var statusLabel: UILabel!
}
```

However when the TableViewController is getting loaded, the app crashes with the error as below

```
Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x10816c540) to 'eCommerceApp.BooksTableViewCell' (0x1069ee5d8).
```

I have done exactly the same thing( with different resuse identifier) for another TableViewController in the same app and it works well.

Its only in this 2nd TableViewController, there is a crash.

I am trying to search the object , the memory address is referring to  '(0x10816c540)' and don't see any matching object in the debugger.(drilled down to every object available)
Is there a way to reverse engineer, or print the object details from the memory address ?

Also appreciate if you can help me identify any obvious reason for the crash.

Comment: A common cause of this error is that you forgot to set the class of the prototype cell to BooksTableViewCell in the Storyboard.

Comment: Bingo ! when I said I did everything I was wrong. Thanks for the answer. It works. I would like to confirm and accept this as answer if you please add it in Answer section

Comment: `0x10816c540` is an instance of `UITableViewCell`. That's what your debugger logs is telling you. The exact object is that which is returned by the `dequeueTableViewCell`.

Comment: right ok, got it. just that the UITableViewCell wasn't referenced with the above memory address.